# Seleniumwire и утечка DNS

Tags: python, сеть, proxy, dns

```
proxy_info = Proxy().Thailand1()

proxy = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'{proxy_info.type}://{proxy_info.username}:{proxy_info.password}@{proxy_info.hostname}:{proxy_info.port}',
        'https': f'{proxy_info.type}://{proxy_info.username}:{proxy_info.password}@{proxy_info.hostname}:{proxy_info.port}',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    },
}

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_argument(f"user-agent={useragent}")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(seleniumwire_options=proxy, options=options, executable_path=chromedriver)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(url)
```

Проверял я прокси через Proxifier с включенной настройкой *resolve hostname through proxy* и утечек DNS не было [image: Настройка DNS у Proxifier]. Но используя seleniumwire сайты видят мой настоящий DNS[image: Видно мой настоящий DNS, но с прокси]. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ - [Use socks5h when you want DNS resolution to happen on the proxy server rather than on the client.](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) Нужно вместо *socks5://* написать *socks5h://*

```
    proxy = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': f'{proxy_info.type}h://{proxy_info.username}:{proxy_info.password}@{proxy_info.hostname}:{proxy_info.port}',
        'https': f'{proxy_info.type}h://{proxy_info.username}:{proxy_info.password}@{proxy_info.hostname}:{proxy_info.port}',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1'
    },
}
```